# jQuery Hover-Over / Active Tab Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

First of all, here is my site I am working on: http://daysofthedead.net/los_angeles/index6.php

What I'd like to do is make the 3 buttons at the bottom of the screen function like the 3 buttons towards the top of the screen.

When you hover-over the images "Friday Lineup April 5th", "Saturday Lineup April 6th", or "Sunday Lineup Aptril 7th" then the image changes, and when it's on that tab (active) the image stays on that alternate image.

I just can't figure out a way to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT: I got it to work using the following code thanks to Explosion Pills.**

```
    $('.panelbuttons .day-1-link').addClass('selected');

    $('.day-1-link').on('click', function () {
         $('[class^=day-]').removeClass('selected');
         $('.panelbuttons .day-1-link').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('.day-2-link').on('click', function () {
         $('[class^=day-]').removeClass('selected');
         $('.panelbuttons .day-2-link').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('.day-3-link').on('click', function () {
       $('[class^=day-]').removeClass('selected');
       $('.panelbuttons .day-3-link').addClass('selected');
    });​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way of doing it would be:

```
$('[class^=day-]').on('click', function () {
   $('[class^=day-]').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Then updated your css so that "selected" uses the different image.